# background image for button refusing to play nice

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I'm missing something obvious and simple but can't see it no matter how hard I squint or glare at the screen.

I'd like to use an image as the background or instead of the button.  It's not displaying.

markup and css:

```css
 #switch {
    background: url("../images/swap.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="conversionFormE" id="switch1">
     <label> &nbsp; </label>
     <input type="button" id="switch" name="switch" value="SWITCH!" onclick="switchUnits()"/>
</div>
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: You have triple-checked your background image path?

Comment: Perhaps you've chosen a wrong path or misspelled the image's name?

Comment: yup, it;s correct, will test with another image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uvxrV/ <- your CSS is correct, your image must be on a different URL

Comment: ah...I tested witha  loading.gif that I have.  I can see the loading circles rotate within the button so I'm assuming it's due to the size of the image?  Perhaps the transparent corner is all that is being shown.

Comment: How big it the image? Is it possible that it is being clipped? Use a developer tool to verify that the image file is being loaded. try adding `background-size:75px;`

Comment: thanks all. Image is too big. Anyone want to post the answer?

Comment: I think there is an issue with the image, even after scaing it down it won't appear, other png's and gif's within the same folder location work fine.  madness.

Comment: are you sure that the swap.png is a png file? (for example: didn't you renamed it from another extension to png? - it may cause problems)

Comment: @falsarella it's a .png.  Now working though.  I can only assume there was a delay in it actually being on the server? I'd uploaded it, refreshed the cache etc when testing but then i tried again and it worked, same code etc.  Suppose it's hat happens when ou use a free hosting company:)

Comment: probably. ctrl + f5 helps to clear browser caching.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is too big, it may be clipped to the point where you don't see it. Try adding:

```
background-size:75px;
```

to see if it appears. (Note that IE prior to 9 doesn't support background-size, so if you need support old IE, the easiest solution is to shrink the image file. Or use a filter to shrink it in IE).